# weekly total and monthly total hours

Tags: sql, sum

```
 s.LastName + ',' + s.FirstName as formattedName
   ,t.Date
   ,RIGHT (t.In1, 7) AS TineIn1
   ,RIGHT (t.Out1, 7) AS TimeOut1
   ,RIGHT (t.In2, 7) AS TimeIn2
   ,RIGHT (t.Out2, 7) AS TimeOut1
   ,RIGHT (t.In3, 7) AS TimeIn3
   ,RIGHT (t.Out3, 7) AS TimeOut3
   , (ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second,t.IN1,t.Out1),0)
     +ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second,t.IN2,t.Out2),0)
     +ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second,t.IN3,t.Out3),0))/3600.0 AS WorkedHours
```

I can get total hour for a day, but How can I get total hours worked for a week, and for a month as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select employee_fullname, 
 (select  (ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second,t.IN1,t.Out1),0)
  +ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second,t.IN2,t.Out2),0)
  +ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second,t.IN3,t.Out3),0))/3600.0 AS WorkedHours
   from timesheet
   where t.in1 between 'cut-off-start' and 'cut-off-end' ) totalHoursWorked
 from employeemaster
```

if t.in1 denotes the 1st time in of the day.

cut-off-start / cut-off-end  (date range whether week or month)

Comment: Thank you, but Not quite working, there is no error message but no value returned either.

Comment: can you paste your code here? and are you able to show us your top 10 records?

Comment: actually on the subquery where clause ... please include t1.employee_code = empmaster.empcode. that's missing

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT 
 s.LastName + ',' + s.FirstName as formattedName
 ,t.Date
 ,RIGHT (t.In1, 7) AS TineIn1
 ,RIGHT (t.Out1, 7) AS TimeOut1
 ,RIGHT (t.In2, 7) AS TimeIn2
 ,RIGHT (t.Out2, 7) AS TimeOut1
 ,RIGHT (t.In3, 7) AS TimeIn3
 ,RIGHT (t.Out3, 7) AS TimeOut3
 ,(SELECT (ISNULL (DATEDIFF(second,t.In1,t.Out1),0)
   +ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second,t.In2,t.Out2),0)
   +ISNULL(DATEDIFF(second,t.In3,t.Out3),0))/3600.0 AS HoursW
    FROM Time t
    WHERE t.StudentID = :parm_lb_StudentEE.StudentID AND t.In1 BETWEEN :parm_dt_StartDate AND :parm_dt_EndDate)as Total_Hour
       , SUM

Comment: I could not post the code here in comment box, so I have posted my code in a new thread, please help me there